# How can i inject css file to djit editor

Tags: dojo

I have a dijit editor :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" id="content" data-dojo-props='value:"", style="width:650px;height:350px;">
```

Because of dijit editor is an Iframe, so I can't use the parent document css in that iframe. My question is: How can i inject my css file named : editorCss.css or tag  to that iframe editor?

Best regards...JaclBlack

Comment: Are you just trying to style the editor?

Comment: yes, I want to insert css or javascript to the editor to style or do something with the content of the editor such as: float image left, right, or edit image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div 
    id="content"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor"
    data-dojo-props="styleSheets: 'path/to/editorCss.css'"
></div>
```